# Nested Accordion plus/minus icon jQuery class selector trouble

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got nested accordions in Bootstrap and have added a plus/minus icon to the title to toggle on accordion show/hide. The problem is that with the jQuery selectors I'm using, when one of the child accordions show/hide, the plus/minus icon changes -- BUT the parent plus/minus icon changes also. What am I doing wrong here with the selectors?

Here is the structure:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">Kiewit</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne1">East</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">Content here...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2">West</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">Content here...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">Vulcan Materials</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Content here...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree">Copper Springs</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Content here...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus:first").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
  }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus:first").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

I add "submenu" class to the plus/minus icon in the nested accordion, the way to stop the outer accordion menu to trigger hidden event is to stop the propagation of the event triggered in the inner accordion.

You can try

```
$('#accordion2 .panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).prev().find(".submenu").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

or just simply `return false` just like the method shown in following bootply

http://www.bootply.com/nLC4Mw3Vqr

Comment: The example you linked to does not work (parent elements do not toggle plus and minus icons), however, the event.stopPropagation() call is what I was missing, and that fixed my problem, thanks!